# Create New SQL Server Login/User for Localhost DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication

I'm new with SQL Server Admin tasks and I'd like to practise adding new logins and users to specific databases. Then I want to play around with Schemas.

This is what I've done:

```
Use master

CREATE LOGIN TestLogin WITH PASSWORD = 'ABC123'
GO


Use DWAdventureWorksLT2012Lab01;
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'TestLogin')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [Michael] FOR LOGIN [TestLogin]
    EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'Michael'
END;
GO
```

I then try to log in with the credentials `TestLogin` and Password `ABC123` but I get an Error
[image]

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your connection properties, but in `CREATE LOGIN` have you tried adding `, default_database = DWAdventureWorksLT2012Lab01`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried that and didn't work. I thought that the login has nothing to do with the DB. What connection properties are you referring to?

Comment: Logins operate at the server level. When creating a Login you can specify a default database and that's the database a connection will be dropped into if you don't specify `Database=...` or `Initial Catalog=...` in your connection string. Users operate at the database level and you need to link Users to Logins for security to work properly.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning correct. That's what I did with the code above but no luck. Even when using the GUI, I'm unable to log in. When logging in, I should select SQL Server Authentication, then only typing in the user name and password. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Well, it depends... If the details you're trying to use are for a Windows account you should be choosing `Windows Authentication` on the Connect to Server dialog which disables the User name and Password fields. This also implies that the create login statement should be something like `create login [SomeDomain\TestLogin] from windows with default_database=DWAdventureWorksLT2012Lab01;`.

Comment: If it's meant to be a login that only exists inside SQL Server, a SQL Login, then choose `SQL Server Authentication` on the Connect to Server dialog, and the create login statement should be something like `create login TestLogin with password='ABC123', default_database=DWAdventureWorksLT2012Lab01;`. Remember that in both cases password characters are case-sensitive.